# undefined reference to system call added to kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

After adding the system call to kernel I tried to compile the kernel.
It ran for 2 hours and at the end threw

> undefined reference to <system call added by me>

[image: system call added by me]

Any idea what had happened.

**Kernel 3.9.3**

**Steps followed are -**

1. Get kernel codes from [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org).
   `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.3.1.tar.bz2`
2. Upzip it with command `tar xvfj XXX` to a folder example :
   `/root/kernel tar xvfj linux-3.3.1.tar.bz2`
3. Edit file `/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` and add new line `312 64 husky1 sys_husky1`
4. Edit file `/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/include/linux/syscalls.h` Add new function before the line `#endif` declaration
   `asmlinkage long sys_husky1(int fd);`
5. Add a new c file under `/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/kernel` (I am using x86 CPU) Example :

   **Edit** `/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/kernel/Makefile` Add a new line
    `obj-y += husky.o`
6. Go to `/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1` folder and run command `make –j8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search your syscall_64.tbl file for "sys_hello_rana". I am guessing you named your syscall as "sys_hello_rana" in syscall table but you used a different name(sys_husky1) when you defined it.